# Android Can't set image in a ListView layout

Tags: android, image, listview, simpleadapter

Looks like find the image but i don't know how to insert into the simple adapter (or anything that let me set the image in my layout)
https://gyazo.com/61ab064c19ae50090f08e6436776a52e

I want to set an image for each object in the array, like:

```
monsterimglist.setImageResource(R.mipmap.icon_name);
```

For the moment im testing to show `R.mipmap.a1` in all the array items in the listview.

**Error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference**

Someone can help me? Thanks a lot

```
ListView monsterslistview;
ImageView monsterimg;
TextView monstername;
TextView monstertype;

private static String monsterid;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MonstersList;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_monsters);

    //Fiquem els elements creats la seva id corresponent
    monstername = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.namelayout);
    monstertype = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.typelayout);
    monsterslistview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.monsterslistview);
    monsterimg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imglayout);


    HashMap<String, String> hashMap;

    //Creem un nou objecte ArrayList per inserir les dades
    MonstersList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    //..........Process JSON DATA................
        try {
            JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());

            //Guardem a un Array de tipus JSON les dades
            JSONArray jr = reader.getJSONArray("monsters");
            for (int i = 0; i < jr.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObjectLine = jr.getJSONObject(i);

                // Desem els items JSON en una variable
                String id = jsonObjectLine.getString("id");
                String name = jsonObjectLine.getString("name");
                String type = jsonObjectLine.getString("type");
                String icon = jsonObjectLine.getString("icon");

                //Toast.makeText(ListMonsters.this, id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                // Afegim la clau-valor a un objecte HashMap
                hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                hashMap.put("id", id);
                hashMap.put("name", name);
                hashMap.put("type", type);
                hashMap.put("icon", icon);
                MonstersList.add(hashMap);

                //mostrem per pantalla els elements que volem mostar
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        ListMonsters.this,
                        MonstersList,
                        R.layout.onemonster,
                        new String[]{"name", "type","icon"},
                        new int[]{R.id.namelayout, R.id.typelayout, R.id.imglayout}

                );
                //Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(R.mipmap.a1).into(monsterimglist);
                monsterslistview.setAdapter(adapter);
                //String idagafat = MonstersList.get(i).get("icon").replace(" ", "");
                monsterimg.setImageResource(R.mipmap.a1);




                monsterslistview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        /**
                        String idagafat = MonstersList.get(position).get("id").replace(" ", "");
                        String positionagafada = String.valueOf(position);
                        openmonster(idagafat, positionagafada);
                         **/


                    }
                });

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


// Funció llegir json
public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
    String json = null;
    try {
        InputStream is = ListMonsters.this.getAssets().open("monsters.json");
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return json;
}

public void openmonster(String id, String pos){
    int posarray = Integer.parseInt(pos);


    Toast.makeText(ListMonsters.this, MonstersList.get(posarray).get("icon").replace(" ", ""), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //Toast.makeText(ListMonsters.this, MonstersList.get(posarray).get("name").replace(" ", ""), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //Toast.makeText(ListMonsters.this, MonstersList.get(posarray).get("type").replace(" ", ""), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

Comment: show your monsters.json file

Comment: @Bunny i think that JSON works fine cause i can display all the fields and fil them in the listview (like name or type) the problem is display the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close the Bracket before creating the adapter.May be it will change your result.

Updated :

```
    ListView monsterslistview; ImageView monsterimg; TextView monstername; TextView monstertype;

private static String monsterid; ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MonstersList;


@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_monsters);

    //Fiquem els elements creats la seva id corresponent
    monstername = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.namelayout);
    monstertype = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.typelayout);
    monsterslistview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.monsterslistview);
    monsterimg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imglayout);


    HashMap<String, String> hashMap;

    //Creem un nou objecte ArrayList per inserir les dades
    MonstersList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    //..........Process JSON DATA................
        try {
            JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());

            //Guardem a un Array de tipus JSON les dades
            JSONArray jr = reader.getJSONArray("monsters");
            for (int i = 0; i < jr.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObjectLine = jr.getJSONObject(i);

                // Desem els items JSON en una variable
                String id = jsonObjectLine.getString("id");
                String name = jsonObjectLine.getString("name");
                String type = jsonObjectLine.getString("type");
                String icon = jsonObjectLine.getString("icon");

                //Toast.makeText(ListMonsters.this, id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                // Afegim la clau-valor a un objecte HashMap
                hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                hashMap.put("id", id);
                hashMap.put("name", name);
                hashMap.put("type", type);
                hashMap.put("icon", icon);
                MonstersList.add(hashMap);

    }   //-----This Bracket was missed in your code


                //mostrem per pantalla els elements que volem mostar
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        ListMonsters.this,
                        MonstersList,
                        R.layout.onemonster,
                        new String[]{"name", "type","icon"},
                        new int[]{R.id.namelayout, R.id.typelayout, R.id.imglayout}

                );
                //Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(R.mipmap.a1).into(monsterimglist);
                monsterslistview.setAdapter(adapter);
                //String idagafat = MonstersList.get(i).get("icon").replace(" ", "");
                monsterimg.setImageResource(R.mipmap.a1);




                monsterslistview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        /**
                        String idagafat = MonstersList.get(position).get("id").replace(" ", "");
                        String positionagafada = String.valueOf(position);
                        openmonster(idagafat, positionagafada);
                         **/


                    }
                });

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


// Funció llegir json public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
    String json = null;
    try {
        InputStream is = ListMonsters.this.getAssets().open("monsters.json");
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return json; }

public void openmonster(String id, String pos){
    int posarray = Integer.parseInt(pos);


    Toast.makeText(ListMonsters.this, MonstersList.get(posarray).get("icon").replace(" ", ""), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //Toast.makeText(ListMonsters.this, MonstersList.get(posarray).get("name").replace(" ", ""), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //Toast.makeText(ListMonsters.this, MonstersList.get(posarray).get("type").replace(" ", ""), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }
```

Comment: Can you give me more details?

Comment: I think the syntax is correct, add this bracket cause a syntax error. My problem is that i can't load the image in my layout's image view and i don't know how to implement in the adapter or whats the correct way to implement it in my code. But thanks MSD

Comment: int id = getBaseContext()getResources().getIdentifier("XXX", "mipmap", getBaseContext().getPackageName());
image.setImageResource(id);

Comment: Looks like the problem is in the adapter, because your code works if i use it in a imageview outside the  "try-catch / adapter" CODE. May be i'll need to create a new adapter wich allows me set images in my listview.